# Where is a good place to find writing prompts?

Tags: brainstorming, writers-block, ideas, preparation

I love using writing prompts to come up with story ideas. I'm looking for good sites that have a lot of good writing prompts. One that updates fairly often would be best. :)

Comment: I'm going to start a bounty for this.  What I will be looking for in awarding the bounty is an answer that lists not only *what* the prompt is (where you can find it and the genre), but *why* it is helpful.  Specific examples of what you've learned, how the prompt has become part of a piece, etc. would be helpful.

Comment: Related: [Resource for generic plot hooks?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7052/)

Comment: Please note that this question has been retained for historical reasons, and shouldn't be considered a good example of an on-topic question for this site.

Answer (score 7):

I know [Writing Excuses](http://www.writingexcuses.com/) has a writing prompt at end of each weekly show. Usually they are related to the topic of the show as well.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't read it myself, but I think [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1582973512), *The 3 A.M. Epiphany* by Brian Kitely, sounds like exactly what you're looking for. It's got very nice reviews - both in terms of score, and the actual description. Here's the first one that sounded like a great match for your question:

> The exercises also have an additional dimension to them that most don't. Each one is 
>   carefully constructed to help you explore a certain aspect of your writing. These aren't 
>   meant to be "merely" inspirational--they're designed to teach technique, as well, without 
>   reading like a dry instructional book.
>
> There are types of exercises in here I really haven't seen anywhere else, particularly in 
>   the sections on "Internal Structure" and "Exercises for Stories in Progress", and I think 
>   you'll find them inspiring in ways that other books aren't. They'll make you think, work 
>   and write in whole new directions.

It sounds so tempting, I'm inclined to get a copy myself. :)

Comment: I own a copy. It is definitely pretty helpful.

Comment: Oh, good :) I ordered one a couple weeks back.

Answer (score 4):

I love [The Writer's Book of Matches](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158297411X) for fiction writing prompts.

Answer (score 4):

Not a writing prompt in a traditional sense, but this has worked for me: improv comedy classes.  Every time you perform a scene, you're creating a completely new story on the fly.  It's a great way to generate ideas.  The story grows organically, and you'll get unexpected (i.e. creative) results.

It's a fun way to get new ideas for writing.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.sfwa.org/2011/03/guest-post-an-infinite-supply-of-writing-prompts) describes an interesting system for coming up with infinite writing prompts through Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

[Type Trigger](http://typetrigger.com/)
is rather fun - you get a very short prompt (one to three words) and then write up to three hundred words on that prompt. There's a new prompt every hour. It's an energetic little writing exercise.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.seventhsanctum.com/generate.php?Genname=writechallenge
Updated every time you click

Answer (score 1):

[Writing Prompt Websites](http://melydia.zoiks.org/writing/writing-prompt-websites/)

This is basically a link to an existing list elsewhere. That's because I think the most important aspects of writing prompts are:

1. A variety of compelling topics
2. A sense of community for peer support

The definition of each of these will differ for anyone asking this question, so the best answer is a list with diverse topics and diverse peers.

Answer (score 1):

This, I think, is a writing prompt tool unlike any other.  Whereas most prompts just start you off, this one can assist you with the continuation of your story.

It provides multiple ways to get a prompt depending on your mood or goal.  Whether you want a complete scenario, a starting scene, a goal, or a character, you just click a button.

I recommend reading some of the example stories to get an idea of how people are using it here:
[Actual Play Reports](http://www.rpgsolo.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=4)

Here is the home page that has some more information on it: http://www.rpgsolo.com

If you get lost there is great documentation in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding a source of explicit and structured prompts, I opt to look for randomized inspiration.  Every day or two, I do the following:

- http://www.flickr.com/explore - I browse until I find 3-5 images that strike a chord of interest in me (for any reason).
- http://live.lmgtfy.com/ - I watch these live search terms with a text editor open and simply choose 5-10 individual words that pop up (again, whatever grabs me that day), writing them down.

Almost without fail, when I smash the words up against the images, I get struck with a nugget of a "wouldn't that be interesting..." kind of idea, then I write anywhere from 200-500 words on the topic.  These short exercises are always brief and not well fleshed out, and they are often terrible.  I write until the core of the idea is laid out, then I stop and file them into a folder with all the rest.

But the point isn't to get a winner every time, the point is that much later, when I'm ready to begin writing a new story, I don't need to go looking for prompts or ideas... I have a collection of dozens (or more) ideas that I've already had.  All I have to do is browse through them and I *always* find at least a few that inspire me to explore them further.