# Where should I start if I'm feeling the urge to write something?

Tags: writers-block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help! I've got Writer's Block](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/help-ive-got-writers-block)

For the past few weeks I have had this "itch" to write something - anything. As soon as I try to put pen to paper, though, my mind goes blank.

Does anybody have any thoughts on where to start? The last time I wrote something "read-worthy" was back in high school (and that was 7 years ago).