# A Wishing stone needs to be destroyed?

Tags: creative-writing

In my story the protagonist has to destroy a magic wishing stone. Any ideas? The stone is marble and it talks!!

Comment: Sorry, but this question is off topic here as it's just a request for ideas. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. However, if you're struggling with writer's block, [this question might help](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/2100/23436).

Comment: Hit it really really hard?  Seriously, marble is far from indestructible.

Comment: To destroy anything, simply throw it into Mt Doom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sledgehammer/crush it. Fire/burn it. Bury it under the ocean. Send it to outer space. Cuts its mouth open. Cover its mouth/suffocate it.

Comment: I never thought about the mouth thing. Brilliant ) Thanks. Sorry that is off topic didn't know where to put it.

Comment: Fans of the Rocky & Bullwinkle cartoons will have a ready answer:  "I wish you'd shut up."